# Display Usernotification upon silent Push Notification when app is in background

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, unusernotificationcenter

This is my scenario:
My app receives a push notification, with payload

```
"aps": {
            "content-available": 1,
            "alert": "hello",
            "sound": ""
          }
```

When received, based upon additional values in the payload, I decide whether or not to display a  UserNotification as such:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
 if mylogic = true{
 self.scheduleNotification(userInfo: userInfo, inSeconds: 1, completion: { success in
                    if success {
                      print("Successfully scheduled notification")
                    } else {
                      print("Error scheduling notification")
                    }
                  })
}
}
```

This works fine when the app in the foreground, but not in the background

conditions:
-Development Profile
-Untethered debugging
-Xcode 12 Beta

Is this expected behavior, and if so, how do I manage to display a User Notification when the app in the background?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have read some documentation...
Here
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns/
if found the following:

"background
Use the background push type for notifications that deliver content in the background, and don’t trigger any user interactions. If you set this push type, the apns-topic header field must use your app’s bundle ID as the topic."

That did the trick for me